# Connect to WiFi with a hidden SSID on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, gnome, network-manager, 18.04

Is it possible to connect to Wi-Fi with a hidden SSID using the GNOME DE that now comes with Ubuntu 18.04?

I've done the usual googles and searches and not been able to find an answer.

If not what is the best and securest way to set this up through the terminal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Launch *Settings* and go to *Wi-Fi* section. Click on the three dots icon at top-right, you'll get a "*Connect to Hidden Network...*" option.

[image]